# making a sequentie complementair

Tags: python, input, error-handling, sequences, except

I have written a script which reads an input sequence, but this sequence must be written with your Caps lock on! How can i except this error ask for a new sequence if Caps lock was not on?

I have:

```
while True:
try:
    seq = input ("voer uw sequentie in, IN HOOFDLETTERS: ")

    break
except (ValueError, IndexError, KeyError ):
    print("voer uw sequentie in , IN HOOFDLETTERS")
```

But this code doesn't do anything with the sequence if they are written with the Caps lock off.

Can someone give me a hand

**i have posted mij question here under about het complementair sequence !**

---

i Have to make the next frames :

```
`+3 SerIleLeuAlaStpProLysTrpGluProProTyrValAlaStpProIleTyrIleTyrTle`
```

`+2 PheAsnThrSerMetThrLysValGlyThrProLeuArgSerMetThrHisIleTyrIleTyr`

`+1 PheGlnTyrStpHisAspGlnSerGlyAsnProLeuThrStpHisAspProTyrIleTyrIle`

`TTTCAATACTAGCATGACCAAAGTGGGAACCCCCTTACGTAGCATGACCCATATATATATATATA`

`TATATATATATATATGGGTCATGCTACGTAAGGGGGTTCCCACTTTGGTCATGCTAGTATTGAAA`

`-1 TyrIleTyrIleTyrGlySerCysTyrValArgGlyPheProLeuTrpSerCysStpTyrStp`

`-2 IleTyrIleTyrMetGlyHisAlaThrOc*GlyGlySerHisPheGlyHisAlaSerIleglu`

`-3 TyrIleTyrIleTrpValMetLeuArgLysGlyValProThrLeuValMetLeuValLeuLys`

the sequentie in the middle is my input sequence,  the sequentie under mijn input sequences is mijn complementair sequence,,, the +1 is translations of my whole seq. +2 is translations beginning with position 1 and +3 begins with position 2 ( counting begins with zero )

the -1,-2 and -3 are the same calculating but now i have to use mine complementair seq.

the first frames i have done, but i can't make my seq , complementair .
i have it done with the next script :

```
def translate(seq):
        x = 0
        aaseq = []
        while True:
            try:
                aaseq.append(dicti[seq[x:x+3]])
                x += 3
            except (IndexError, KeyError):
                break
        return aaseq

    for frame in range(3):
        #print(translate(seq[frame:]))

        print(''.join(item.split('|')[0] for item in translate(seq[frame:])))
```

can someone help me with the complementair part ??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you actually check for it being in capital letters. I would recommend using an if then statement rather than a try except statement.

```
while True:
    seq = input("voer uw sequentie in, IN HOOFDLETTERS: ")
    if seq.isupper():
        break
    else:
        print "Input must be IN HOOFDLETTERS"
```

Alternatively you could also just take the user input and capitalize it yourself.

Comment: I edited your code to be in Python (since that's the tag on the question) - hope you don't mind.

Comment: The tag wasn't there when I answered it, so thanks for your help :)